# Scala PackratParser ignores failure parser

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators

I have a parser that was written using Scala's `RegexParsers` - [link](https://github.com/adamretter/csv-validator/blob/master/csv-validator-core/src/main/scala/uk/gov/nationalarchives/csv/validator/schema/SchemaParser.scala)

It had some serious performance problems when parsing a grammar which had deeply nested expressions. As such I have created a version where I mix in Scala's `PackratParsers` - [link](https://github.com/adamretter/csv-validator/blob/packrat-parsers/csv-validator-core/src/main/scala/uk/gov/nationalarchives/csv/validator/schema/SchemaParser.scala)

The Packrat version does not exhibit the same performance issue and correctly parses the grammar. However, when I provide an invalid grammar for testing, e.g. [this](https://github.com/adamretter/csv-validator/blob/packrat-parsers/csv-validator-core/src/test/scala/uk/gov/nationalarchives/csv/validator/schema/SchemaParserRulesSpec.scala#L138)

The old (non-packrat) parser used to correctly report the 'Invalid rule' failure, via the *failure* parser combinator `| failure("Invalid rule")` here - [link](https://github.com/adamretter/csv-validator/blob/master/csv-validator-core/src/main/scala/uk/gov/nationalarchives/csv/validator/schema/SchemaParser.scala#L511)

When using the packrat-parser version, if I enable tracing I can see from the trace that the failure is created just as it is in the non-packrat version, however the PackratParser seems to ignore this and always return `failure: Base Failure` instead.

Is there something different about failure handling when using PackratParsers which I need to understand?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you need to use `err("Invalid rule")` instead of `failure`, as it guarantees that no backtracking will be performed.

Comment: If I use `err("Invalid rule")` instead of `failure("Invalid rule")` then because backtracking has stopped, many of my other rules that were previously valid start returning `err("Invalid rule")` which is not correct.